# Converting to binary in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, string, matlab, binary

I have some Matlab code that I am trying to convert to Python.

In Matlab the code takes a string and converts it to a double, then to binary.

```
x = dec2bin(double(string), 8);
```

Now, the string has numbers, letters, decimal points, and commas. Matlab has no problems converting this.

Is there anything in Python that can do this?

I've tried using `bin()`, changing the string to a float first, various Numpy options like:

```
x = numpy.base_repr(string, 2, 8)
```

and

```
numpy.binary_repr()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it easily with:

```
>>> string = "foo"
>>> res = [bin(ord(i)) for i in string]
['0b1100110', '0b1101111', '0b1101111']
```

The same example in matlab gives the same result:

```
>>> dec2bin(double('foo'), 8)
01100110
01101111
01101111
```